# Customize Allow Flash Bubble on Chrome

Tags: javascript

Hi i just want to know is it possible for us to capture allow flash event in chrome using Javascript and customize the message shown and event for clicking allow or block.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR;

**NO**

This is a built in Browser feature. Much like an `alert()` or `confirm()`.
We are not given the freedom to customize this.

For a good reason!

Flash is considered a security-breach-enabler. If I were to be allowed to customize this popup, I'd make it to look like "Say HI", you click "hi" and flash get's enabled, and I take control over your machine.

So. We do not stylize it to make sure we are all secure.